# Backbone Views UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

I am wondering if there is a better way of doing this.

I have some HTML that needs some events attaching to it.

Question 1:
There is no data, models or collections behind it so I assume no need for a render method?

Question 2:
I am assuming it should be a view in backbone because it is a single piece of UI that needs code attaching to it?

Basically what I have is a panel with show and hide functionality, which shows some check boxes for saving settings. When the panel closes it will save the states of the check boxes.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="panel-holder">
<div id="settings">
  <ul class="settingsChecks">
    <li>
      <label>Display Desktop Notification Popup&nbsp;</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="formDisplayPopup" checked="checked"/>
    </li>           
    <li>
      <label>Play Alert Sound&nbsp;</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="formPlaySounds" checked="checked"/>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

So the above code is attached to a view using #panel-holder.

Here is the Backbone code:

```
var SettingsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#panel-holder',
  events: {
    'click #click': 'toggleContent'
  },
  initialize: function() {
    this.toggleContent();
  },
  showmeState: true,
  toggleContent: function(){
    if (this.showmeState === false) {
      this.openPanel();
    } else {
      this.closePanel();
    }
  },
  closePanel: function() {
    this.$el.find('#settings').slideUp('fast');//Close Panel
    this.$el.find('#click').text("Open Settings");//Change Text
    this.showmeState = false;
    this.saveSettings();
  },
    openPanel: function() {
    this.$el.find('#settings').slideDown('fast');//Open Panel
    this.$el.find('#click').text("Close Settings");//Change Text
    this.showmeState = true;
  },
  saveSettings: function() {
    //when the panel closes get the states of the checkboxes and save them
  }
});
```

Question 3:
Should I be using jQuery .find('') in the open and close panel areas? Is there a better way of attaching functionality to these elements.

Question 4:
Is this code and my understanding of Backbone Views ok? Am I way off course?

Comment: I didn't see the #click element but generally I think you get my point below

Answer (score 0):

### Answers

1. I would include a render method that returns itself so that you can append the view to the #panel-holder element
2. Yes, this is fine
3. Always use $.find("") when working within a view's elements. Just index the elements so you can access them as this.$settings, etc
4. No looks good generally

### Code

Here is my recommended code in Coffeescript (sorry I'm lazy):
Also uses [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) library to compile templates

```
tmpl = ....all your html...

SettingsView = Backbone.View.extend

  attributes: 
   id: 'settings'

  template: Handlebars.compile tmpl

  events:
   'click #click': 'toggleContent'

  initialize:
   @toggleContent()

  showMeState: true

  toggleContent: ->
   @showMeState is false then @openPanel()
   else @closePanel()

  closePanel:->
   @$settings.slideUp('fast')
   @$click.text('Open Settings')
   @showMeState = false
   @saveSettings()

  openPanel: ->
   @$settings.slideDown('fast')
   @$click.text('Close Settings')
   @showMeState = true

  saveSettings: ->

  render: ->
   @$el.append @template
   #Store settings and click
   @$settings = @$el.find('#settings')
   @$click = @$el.find('#click')
   @

settings = new SettingsView
$('#panel-holder').append settings.render().el
```

Comment: If `#panel-holder` is an existing `DOM` element then the way the OP is attaching it to the `DOM` should be fine.

Comment: True - well anyways - just my two cents on some things that could be done. This way allows him to modularize his code somewhat by shipping the template along with the view

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1: There is no data, models or collections behind it so I
>   assume no need for a render method?

For now it is not required. But if you want to add extra functionality or if the UI changes in any way later then you might be requiring one.

> Question 2: I am assuming it should be a view in backbone because it
>   is a single piece of UI that needs code attaching to it?

Yes. it is a view.

> Question 3: Should I be using jQuery .find('') in the open and close
>   panel areas? Is there a better way of attaching functionality to these
>   elements.

`this.$el.find('#settings')` is perfectly fine.

You can also use either `$('#settings', this.$el)` or `this.$('#settings')`

But remember that you are using `ID` selectors . And `ID` will be unique on the page. So you do not need to find it in the context of the view

`$('#setting')` should be good enough

> Question 4: Is this code and my understanding of Backbone Views ok? Am
>   I way off course?

You are doing perfectly well. But the thing is in backbone you can get a task done in many ways which works. And you need to choose the best approach amongst them. You will get to know the more you work with it. So do not worry about it.

The same can be condensed into a single method that will take care of toggling

```
var SettingModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        showmeState : false
    }
});

var settingModel = new SettingModel(); 

var SettingsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#panel-holder',
    events: {
        'click #click': 'toggleState'
    },
    initialize: function () {
        // Listen to the Model that triggers 
        this.listenTo(settingModel, 'change', this.toggleContent);
        this.model.trigger('change');
    },
    toggleState: function() {
        //When Clicked just negate the boolean so that it triggers the change event
        this.model.set('showmeState', !this.model.get('showmeState'));
    },
    toggleContent: function() {
        var check = !this.model.get('showmeState'),
            txt = check === true ? "Close Settings" : "Open Settings";
         $('#click').text(txt);
         check === true ? $('#settings').slideUp('fast') 
                        : $('#settings').slideDown('fast');
        if(check)
            saveSettings();
    },
    saveSettings: function () {
        //when the panel closes get the states of the checkboxes and save them
    }
});
```

If you think check for condition is an overkill, then a simple if should be sufficient.